# image redirect to another form in aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my aspx code...

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        Width="88%" Height="100px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table width="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Coupon_Image")%>'
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="20px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <%--<asp:LinkButton   ID="Button1" runat="server" Width="145" Height="34" border="0" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Coupon_Id") %>'
                       CommandName="Get Coupoun"  OnClick="getCoupon_Click"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                        <asp:Button ID="getCoupon" runat="server" Width="145" Height="34" border="0" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Coupon_Id")%>' Text="Get Coupon"
                            OnClick="getCoupon_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

my code in code behind:

```
private void Binddata()
    {


        DataTable dtReport = new DataTable();
        DataColumn Coupon_Id = new DataColumn("Coupon_Id");
        DataColumn Coupon_Image = new DataColumn("Coupon_Image");

        dtReport.Columns.Add(Coupon_Id);
        dtReport.Columns.Add(Coupon_Image);



        string sendquery = "select Coupon_Id,Coupon_Image from Admin where Coupon_Status='Active'";


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sendquery, connection);
        DataSet dsProfile = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dsProfile);
        for (int i = 0; i < dsProfile.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dtReport.NewRow();
            row["Coupon_Id"] = dsProfile.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Coupon_Id"].ToString();
            string id = dsProfile.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Coupon_Id"].ToString();


            string ImgName = dsProfile.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Coupon_Image"].ToString();
            string Path = "http://localhost:2872/arpita-coupons/Coupon_Image/" + ImgName ;

            row["Coupon_Image"] = "<img  src='" + Path + "' height='200px' width='200px'  />";
            hddnpath.Value = Path + ImgName + id;
            dtReport.Rows.Add(row);

        }

        DataList1.DataSource = dtReport;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }


protected void getCoupon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string id = hddnpath.Value;
        string imagename = hddnpath.Value;
        Response.Redirect("deals-forms.aspx?id="+id+" & ImgName="+imagename+" "+"");
    }
```

my question is if i click the button to get the particular image to be redirect to the another page . but i am getting only the different image to the another aspx page...

Answer (score 0):

You set `id` and `imagename` to the same value, then build a link from both. I guess there is the problem somewhere:

```
string id = hddnpath.Value;
string imagename = hddnpath.Value;
Response.Redirect("deals-forms.aspx?id=" + id    // <-- this variable
                + " & ImgName=" + imagename      // <-- and this one both
                + " " + "");                     //     contain hddnpath.Value
```

Comment: string id = hddnpath.Value;
            string imagename = hddnpath.Value;
            Response.Redirect("deals-forms.aspx?id="+id+" & ImgName="+imagename+" ");  actually from this i am getting the id and image .....for eg:there is three images . if click the above process i am getting the lat image.. actually i want to get the first image if i click the button..